# Build a list with length N

Tags: haskell

I am trying to make a function that builds a list based on length n, some initial value, and builds the rest of the list applying some function/operation to the previous value . For example:

n = 5, initial_value = x, -> [x, fx, ... ]

I understand that to make a list of size n you can simply use replicate to give you a list, but perhaps it is not the best way to achieve this.

Code:

```
buildList::Int -> (b -> b) -> b -> [b]
buildList len func initial = replicate len something here
```

Not sure what would come after "len".

EDIT: Thanks for the help. `iterate` is a much better option for a task like this as the values will continuously repeat using `replicate`.

Comment: It's often a good start to check on Hoogle if there's something that might be relevant to your problem. In this case a [search for your signature](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Int+-%3E+(b+-%3E+b)+-%3E+b+-%3E+%5Bb%5D) yields some niche results, but hints that removing the `n` argument might get you somewhere.  And indeed [a search for `(b -> b) -> b -> [b]`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(b%20-%3E%20b)%20-%3E%20b%20-%3E%20%5Bb%5D) yields `iterate`, which would be a big help to you.

Comment: @amalloy, how does it hint that?

Comment: @dfeuer The results are for `iterateN`, suggesting the existence of a function named `iterate` that's popular enough to have variants of it defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replicate` will repeat the *same* value a number of times. That makes not much sense since we start with `x`, `f x`, `f (f x)`, etc.

We can make use of [**`iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate) that will for `iterate f x` construct an infinite list `[x, f x, f (f x), f (f (f x))), …]`.

We then should limit the list to the first *N* items. I leave it as an exercise to do this. The function thus looks like:

```
buildList :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
buildList len func initial = … (iterate func initial)
```

where you still need to implement the `…` part.

Comment: Great advice, thank you. using `take` would solve the sizing issue I believe!

Comment: @user1612508: can you explain how you defined `buildList`?

Comment: it is defined like `buildList::Int -> (b -> b) -> b -> [b]`

Comment: @user1612508: but the implementaiton of the function?

Comment: `buildList 4 x 1` is how I called it